# What would be the best folder structure for nestjs backend for multi users?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, backend

We have three types of users: **clients**,  who are responsible for creating and modifying projects; **freelancers**, who can apply for projects; and **admins**, who can monitor everything.

Creating project modules for **each user type is good**, or we can have **one project module** and role guard in the API?

I am new to the NestJS backend, so any help will be appreciated.

[image]